# SQL statement to get most recent records based on date time

Tags: sql-server

I need help with query to fetch most recent record based on a `DateTime` column in the database. Its format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MINS:SEC:Milliseconds`.

Whenever new records get created in the database, only those records must be fetched and displayed in a third party application.

Below queries fetch all records of the application, can we put it in subquery and pull only recent records or any other best way

```
SELECT 
    User.ID, User_State.Name, User_State.Code, User_State.TestState,
    Details.FirstName, Details.LastName, Details.LoginName,
    User_State.DateTime,call.QueueCalls, call.CallsAband 
FROM 
    User
INNER JOIN 
    User_State ON User.ID = User_State.ID
INNER JOIN 
    Details ON User.ID = Details.ID
INNER JOIN  
    Call ON User_State.Key = Call.Key
WHERE 
    User_State.DateTime >= CONVERT(DateTIme, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())) 
ORDER BY 
    DateTime DESC
```

Comment: Just add a `LIMIT` clause at the end of the query to restrict the number of rows returned e.g. `LIMIT 1` will return *only* the most recent row

Comment: Hi @Nick and welcome to Stack Overflow. I see from your profile that you have posted a number of technical answers/solutions in the comments section recently. Please use the answer section for answers. That way, they can be properly peer reviewed. Comments are for suggesting improvements to a question, requesting clarification, and having pointless fights with people. Cheers!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Point taken. I will try to restrict myself to having pointless fights from now on! :-)

Comment: @Nick Oh it's loads of fun though ;)

Comment: Umn, you tagged that with MySQL but `convert()`, `datediff()` (with precision) and `getdate()` look more like SQL Server. Are you sure it's MySQL you are using?

Comment: My bad, that's a Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that query is returning all rows you can restrict the number of rows either by using TOP n clause with select statement or you can also use row_number() with CTE. Depending upon how many rows you want to return.I don't understand your where clause though.

Example with ROW_number as below -

```
 SELECT row,User.ID, User_State.Name, User_State.Code, User_State.TestState
 , Details.FirstName, Details.LastName, Details.LoginName
 , User_State.DateTime,call.QueueCalls, call.CallsAband 
 FROM(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY User_State.DateTime) AS row,
  User.ID, User_State.Name, User_State.Code, User_State.TestState
 , Details.FirstName, Details.LastName, Details.LoginName
 , User_State.DateTime,call.QueueCalls, call.CallsAband 
 FROM User
  INNER JOIN User_State ON User.ID = User_State.ID
  INNER JOIN Details ON User.ID = Details.ID
  INNER JOIN Call ON User_State.Key = Call.Key
  WHERE User_State.DateTime >= GETDATE()
  ) AS CTE
  where CTE.row<10
 ORDER BY CTE.DateTime DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for you help Gaurav! When I tried above query it throws an error like "Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "User.ID" could not be bound. However, we are using the where to pull only todays data.